# How can i get my python program to get answers from google?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, bots

so, im programming a python AI and im trying to make it as similar as JARVIS from iron man. its going great, but i want to do the following:
So, if you go now and search for "How did Gorge Harrison die?", google will show "Lung Cancer", followed by other websites. I want the AI, when asked this questions, to go to google and store the answer in a variable.

I want to store it in a variable because i am using the os module and i am using it to make the AI talk(os.system("spd-say 'hello'") or os.system("spd-say '" + variable + "'"))

Answer (score 0):

Use the requests module to construct an http request then parse the json that comes back.